# wordpress - upload a file from outside wp uploads

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to attach a file already on server but **outside** the wp uploads directory to a post, so I tried the `media_handle_sideload` and used the `download_url()` on the file's URL I'm trying to attach, however for some reason, the download_url cannot access my server, is there a work around that I can do so instead of giving `media_handle_sideload` a $_FILES array I can give it the file absolute path? Or can I move a file already on server to the temp folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by simulating a $_FILES array:

```
$file_array = array(
     'name' => basename( $file_path ),
     'type' => $url_type,
     'tmp_name' => $file_path,
     'error' => 0,
     'size' => filesize( $file_path )
);
```

And then

```
$att_id = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id );
```